# Remove store code from URL in Magento

Tags: php, .htaccess, magento

I have 2 sites on one Magento install that point to different domains.

Site1 => www.site1.com

Site2 => www.site2.com

Each site shows the store code in the url of category, product, and CMS pages (www.site1.com/store1/category). Is there a way to remove the /store1/ from the url so that is just www.site1.com/category? My guess is that can be done with .htaccess somehow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have two different websites I don't think you need that anyway, I think there is a setting in system < config < web Add Store Code to Urls and you should try setting that to no and then reindex.

Comment: I've set "Add Store Code to Urls" to no before and got __store= in the URL, but I think that was because I had two stores on one site. Now that I only have one store each site this works. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on IIS 7 put the lines below in you web.config file
Replace "nl" with your own storecode and "domain.com" with your domainname.

```
<rules>
    <rule name="301 remove storecode" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url="^nl/(.*)$" ignoreCase="true" />
        <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
            <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="www.domain.com" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.domain.com/{R:1}" />
    </rule>
</rules>
```

Regards,

Answer (score -2):

TRY THIS
.htaccess

```
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9_]+)/category(-([0-9]+))? category.php?store=$1&id=$3 [L]
```